# aggregate group by _parentId

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a list of elements. Some of the have _parentId property pointing to ids of the elements from the same collections. So all elements that have _parentId are children to those elements that have no _parentId.

I need a result, that would contain all parent elements (without _parentId), quantity of child elements and the "content" property of the latest added (it has a dateCreated property) child element for each parent. Ex:

```
[{
   _id: "some id",
   title: "some title",
   email: "some email",
   dateCreated: "date",
   children:{
     count: 7, 
     lastAddedChildContent: "some content", 
     dateCreated: "date:
   }],
  parentCount:23 // total for parent elements
}
```

What is the best way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the design of your original documents that you want to perform aggregation on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fair question. Simplifying the documents a little just for example purposes, say there are documents like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a"),
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2014-08-15T03:46:57.784Z"),
    "title" : "Master",
    "content" : "Orig content"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ed80bba75ca1a5248a281b"),
    "title" : "Other title",
    "content" : "More content",
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2014-08-15T03:38:35.694Z"),
    "_parent" : ObjectId("53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ed80d1a75ca1a5248a281c"),
    "title" : "Other title",
    "content" : "Last content",
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2014-08-15T03:38:57.750Z"),
    "_parent" : ObjectId("53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a")
}
```

Your aggregation pipeline will essentially substitute the `_id` field as appropriate to the parent and then sort the results:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "_id": { "$ifNull": [ "$_parent", "$_id" ] },
        "title": 1,
        "dateCreated": 1,
        "content": 1,
        "_parent": { "$ifNull": [ "$_parent", false ] }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "_parent": -1, "dateCreated": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "title": { "$min": { "$cond": [ "$_parent", false, "$title" ] } },
        "dateCreated": { 
            "$max": { 
                "$cond": [
                    "$_parent",
                    false,
                    "$dateCreated"
                ]
            }
        },
        "childCount": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    "$_parent",
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "lastContent": { "$last": "$content" },
        "lastDate": { "$last": "$dateCreated" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "title": 1,
        "dateCreated": 1,
        "children": {
            "count": "$childCount",
            "lastContent": "$lastContent",
            "dateCreated": "$lastDate"
        }
    }}
])
```

Where the resulting response would be this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ed7efca75ca1a5248a281a"),
    "title" : "Master",
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2014-08-15T03:46:57.784Z"),
    "children" : {
        "count" : 2,
        "lastContent" : "Last content",
        "dateCreated" : ISODate("2014-08-15T03:38:57.750Z")
    }
}
```

The main operators to look at there are [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) which tests for the field presence or indeed a `null` value and either returns the field content or the alternate argument. The other is [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) which is a ternary operator. It evaluates a logical condition or value as it's first argument then either returns the second in the case where that argument is `true` or the last argument where `false`. In modern releases this can even be written as "if .. then .. else" if that seems clearer.

The initial [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is done to essentially feed the information for [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/), which is essentially done as you need the [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operator to form part of your response.

In the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statement, all documents belonging to the "parent" now have the same `_id` as the parent does so that is the correct grouping key. Any "parent fields" are conditionally evaluated so that only that content is returned, this is a creative use on [**`$min`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) here as the "string" is only returned for the "parent" document and that will have a smaller value than `false` which is otherwise returned.

The "count" of children is simple evaluation of whether the document is a "parent" or not when choosing a value to feed to [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/). The other fields along with count are evaluated with `$last` from the sort order, and are all returned separately as you cannot return a "sub-document" form in an aggregation group. These you `$project` later into the required output.

I deliberately messed with the dates there to demonstrate part of the "sort" principle, but this is mainly about the "parent" identification. The other deliberate action is not grouping all "parents" into an array. I don't think that is good practice just to get a count, and it runs a real possibility of breaking the BSON limit of 16MB. If you want a response to look like that for sending elsewhere it is better to post-process and add in the count as you won't have the same restrictions and can use as much memory as you like.

So if you must, then add an additional group to "push" and "count" at the end, but don't say you were not advised better about it when things go wrong.

Comment: Can you tell me, please, how I can count the parent elements?

Comment: Is it possible to add more fields in the output?